# How to save multiple images to the database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to save multiple images of products in the database. I created the images table and set up a relationship with the products table.

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $formInput = $request->all();
    $image = array();
    if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images', $name);
            $image[] = $name;

        }
    }

    //dd($formInput);

    Product::create(array_merge($formInput,
        [
            // 'product_id'=>$product->id,
            'image' => 'what to put here',
            'seller_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        ]));

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Image Model**

```php
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'images';
    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'image'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```php
class product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['seller_id', 'pro_name', 'pro_price', 'pro_info', 'stock', 'category_id'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

When I `dd($formInput)` I see all the details, including images, but how do I submit them to the database? Images to images table and products details to the products table.

Comment: You've asked seven questions on this in the last day or two and you aren't really pulling in the information from the answers that have been given.  May I suggest that you back up a little, and try a few tutorials to help you with some of the fundamentals that I think you may be missing.  Try Laracasts for starters, Jeff Way is excellent.  Not trying to be hard, but I don't think SO will be able to help you build what you need without some foundational knowledge :)

Comment: No hard feelings. I tried to do the way you suggested but i wasn't able to get the product id. @Watercayman

Comment: If you really want to store the image in the database (usually a filesystem is preferable) then use `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use insert images in images table using Image::create() and in images table you should make a foreign key(product_id) to product's id. There will be no entry in Products table regarding images. Just create the products with normal fields and not including any image details.

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
$formInput = $request->all();
$image = array();
if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $image[] = $name;

    }
}

//dd($formInput);
Image::createMany([
'product_id': //'value of id': Same for all images of this product
],[...])

Product::create(array_merge($formInput,
    [
        // 'product_id'=>$product->id,
        // 'image' => 'what to put here',
        'seller_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        //Other Fields' details... 
    ]));

return redirect()->back();
}
```